# vco lowpass etc. don't work. Circuitikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

How come that circuitikz does not give me the vco I intend to build?
See this code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt, 12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz} 
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw   (1,0) to[vco](5,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

But when putting a "R" instead of "vco" it gives me a resistor. Why can't I use vco, lowpass etc? Thanks a lot

EDIT: When I copy+paste the .sty and .cls files from the circuitikz directory into the directory of my project it works. But when I paste the files into my ~/.texmf-var/tex/ dir, it does not work, even if the ksepath-command tells me that this is a directory Tex searches for. Why is that? This is actually another question, but I hope someone helps me anyway. Thanks

Comment: see the documentation: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/circuitikz?lang=de and search for vco. Or am I missing something (forgot some \usepackage  etc.)

Comment: Here, your MWE gives a vco...

Comment: You need to use VCo, not vco.

Comment: I think the `vco` is quite new, as I didn't know this option (and I needed it some time ago), and it's not in my downloaded manual, but in the online manual. Probably, you do not have the newest version of circuittikz. For me, it also doesn't work. I guess this option just exists in the newest circuitikz version...

Comment: Yes right, new stuff. See my comment to the answer below.

Comment: I assume, you installed tex-live with an `apt-get install`?

Comment: yes, when I did it now again it said that nothing was upgraded

Comment: this version always seems to be quite old: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55459/44467

Comment: So, from the link above, I got a solution on my PC (Ubuntu). I made `apt-get remove texlive-base` and then installed it with the installer from https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html
Now the vco-symbol works ;)

Comment: Ok I'll try. Need to eat first, I am getting hangry (hungry + angry):-)

Comment: It may take some time (4GB to download)... ;)

Comment: perhaps you have to run `mktexlsr` if you change something in the installation, but I'm not sure...

Answer (score 3):

The version of `circuitikz` distributed with debian might be quite old, [as stated here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55459/44467). And the keyword `vco` just came into circuitikz with a quite new version, 0.4, which is probably not yet available in the debian repos.

So you could uninstall the "apt-get-version", and install "vanilla" TexLive (see https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html).
Just download and extract the file install-tl-unx.tar.gz, and run the contained installer....

Comment: You added the "updating" tag to the question. As I understand it (https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/updating/info), the tag is about questions concerning "How do I update my distribution?" and not about questions where the answer is "You need to update your used package/distribution/...". Maybe I'm wrong? But +1 for your answer!

Comment: yes, probably you're right!

Answer (score 1):

With `standalone`, use `tikzpicture` environment instead of `circuitikz`.

Circuitikz provides two vco: `VCo` and `vco`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw   (1,0) to[vco](5,0) node[right]{vco};
\draw   (1,2) to[lowpass](5,2) node[right]{lowpass};
\draw   (1,4) to[VCo](5,4) node[right]{VCo};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: this code does not compile for me. I mean the vco below, not the VCo. How can I install the latest package, since it seems to be very new?

Comment: @jjstcool MikTeX, TeXLive and MacTeX provide different update methods.

Comment: I am using Debian and Kile (KDE). I tried to do this: http://www.volkerschatz.com/tex/tpacks.html but cannot find /etc/texmf/texmf.cnf on my system.

Comment: @PaulGaborit, how to replace the curve inside the circle as in `vco` with an `$\epsilon$`? In other words, how to make a diagram with circle and symbol inside?

Comment: @Sigur With `circuittikz`? This seems impossible since this package only provides symbols used in electronics or logic...

Comment: @PaulGaborit, well, I am editing a text and the guy used a scanned picture which contains a battery with plus/minus and above it exactly that circle with `\epsilon`. He is talking about continuous and alternate. Sorry, but I have no idea about circuits.

Comment: @PaulGaborit, I discovered what I need: a symbol for a constant electromotive force with the E inside it.

Answer (score 0):

It is `VCo` and not `vco`

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt, 12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz} 
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw   (1,0) to[VCo](5,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**

As the required symbol is new, you can manually update to the latest version (0.4) from [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/circuitikz/tex) website.

On Windows with MiKTEX 2.9, you can copy all files from the above link to your latex root and `Refresh FNDB`.

Then, try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz} 
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw   (1,0) to[vco](5,0) node[right]{vco};
\draw   (1,2) to[lowpass](5,2) node[right]{lowpass};
\draw   (1,4) to[VCo](5,4) node[right]{VCo};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: VCo and vco are not the same.

Comment: I mean vco, not VCo, lowpass would have therefore been more appropriate for my example...